# Read XML Schema and Data in .NET

Tags: .net, sql-server, xml, xsd

I'm using SQL Server and VB.NET. In my SQL I'm using the following:

```
select top 1 * from tablename where 1=0 for xml auto, type, xmlschema
```

to get the schema for tablename. Then I use

```
select * from tablename where ID=1 for xml, auto, type, elements xsinil, root('xml')
```

to get the data row I'm interested.

If I use the following code in VB:

```
Private ds as New Dataset

ds.ReadXMLSchema("xmlschema.txt")
```

I end up with a ds containing one table with a correctly defined set of columns

If I then try:

```
ds.ReadXML("xmldata.txt")
```

The code succeeds, but I don't have any rows in the table of my dataset.

My question is, what do I need to do in order to read the xml data created by SQL Server into the datatable with the schema specified by SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to include the `XMLSchema` clause in your second (data) query as well as your first (schema) query. If you don't do this then the data output will be missing a namespace and so won't conform to the schema.
2. You need to specify a target namespace for your schema by qualifying the `XMLSchema` directive (e.g. `XMLSchema('http://tempuri.org')`). If you don't do this then SQL Server will generate a namespace for you in each query, and they may not match.
3. You need to make sure that the column lists and the `FOR XML` clauses of the two queries are exactly the same. In your example you've got `xsinil` specified in the data query but not in the schema query.

So here you need to specify something like this for the schema query

```
select top 1 * from tablename 
where 1=0 
for xml auto, type, elements xsinil, root('xml'), xmlschema('http://tempuri.org')
```

And this for the data query

```
select * from tablename 
for xml auto, type, elements xsinil, root('xml'), xmlSchema('http://tempuri.org')
```